# Semantic Logging Application Block with Log4Net?

Tags: log4net, semantic-logging

Is there a way to redirect events logged using the Semantic Logging Application Block to a Log4Net listener?

What I want to do is fully instrument my libraries for SLAB, but in a way that doesn't force my Log4Net users to fully adopt SLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, you can log an object to it and it will serialize it with its default renderers.

log.Debug(new {color="red", int1 = 1});